# Why do we need to upgrade php version and on live server?

Tags: php, laravel-5, version

I have a simple question why do we need to upgrade PHP version on a live server? Is there any good reason to do so? I'm confused; we're using PHP 5.3 and our CEO doesn't want to update to PHP 5.5 which is recommended in Laravel 5. Can somebody give me reason why we should or we shouldn't do it?

Comment: you don't have to its entirely up to you

Comment: Ok thanks for fast respond

Comment: @Dagon You have to. Laravel 5 requires PHP5.5 and uses components that only exist in 5.5. Also not upgrading should be thoroughly discouraged as older versions (like 5.3) are not even supported with security updates.

Comment: It is not "up to you" nor the speed and memory usage matters. Laravel 5 has PHP5.5.9 as [minimum requirement](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1#installation) and will not work if you have a version prior to this release.

Comment: http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2014/12/on-php-version-requirements.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further to some of the comments on your question:

**Do we need to upgrade PHP**

The answer to this part of the question is "No". In some cases it might not be possible to upgrade as newer version can cause applications to break if they rely on older features.

**Do we need to upgrade PHP for Laravel 5**

The answer to this part is "Yes". You will **have** to upgrade for Laravel 5 as it relies on newer features of PHP that only exist from [PHP 5.4 (Laravel 5)](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0#server-requirements) and [5.5.9 (Laravel 5.1)](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1#installation).

**Should we upgrade PHP**

You didn't ask this question, but I put it in here because **Yes, you should**. Versions of PHP have a *lifetime*. They are supported in full for bugs for a while, and then they are supported for security flaws for slightly longer. However, after a while, versions of PHP will no longer receive any support. Security holes might be found in older version that will never be patched. You should keep your version of PHP up to date in order to remain safe from PHP vulnerabilities that may have been discovered.

As always, the PHP website contains all the information about the currently supported versions of PHP: http://php.net/supported-versions.php

Comment: That's not entirely true. [Laravel 5 depends on PHP 5.4](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0#server-requirements), and [Laravel 5.1 depends on PHP 5.5.9](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1#installation)

Comment: Thanks to you I finally understand.